# How can I plot the routing from two cities,like from Milan to Paris?

Tags: r, routes, location, maps, leaflet

How can I plot the routing from two cities,like from Milan to Paris,using leaflet?or several cities,plotting a network.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please hover over the R tag - it asks you to provide a minimal reproducible example of what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it roughly like this:

```
library(googleway)
library(leaflet)
key <- "********************" # Google Directions API Key
df <- googleway::google_directions("milan", "paris", "driving", key=key)
pl <- df$routes$overview_polyline$points
line <- decode_pl(pl)
bb <- sp::bbox(as.matrix(line))
leaflet() %>% 
  fitBounds(bb[2,1],bb[1,1],bb[2,2],bb[1,2]) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolylines(data=line, lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat)
```

[image]

Get a key [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start).

Comment: you can also plot a google map in googleway using the polyline : `google_map(key = key) %>% add_polylines(data = data.frame(pl = line), polyline = "pl")`

Comment: @SymbolixAU Good to know, and nice package btw - thanks.